# How to submit the custom form data in database in WordPress without plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, database

I have a created a contact form in the `function.php` and added short code on my page and it's working. I am getting my form.

```
function st_contact_form(){
ob_start();
    ?>
      <div class="contact_form-wrapper popup-contact-form">
         <form action="" method="post" name="contact_form" id="contact_form" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="row">      
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
             <div class="form-group">
               <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" required>
             </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
             <div class="form-group">
               <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Id" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
    </div>
 </div>  
 <div class="row">    
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
         <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="mobileno" placeholder="Phone no" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
        <div class="form-group select-service">
            <select class="form-control" name="type_of_services" required>
                <option selected disabled>Select Service</option>
                <option value="1">Testing one</option>
                <option value="2">Testing two</option>

            </select>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 paddingLR0">
         <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Message" name="message" rows="2" required></textarea>
         </div>
    </div>
         <div class="form-group ">
            <input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit" class="btn_st btn_maroon form_submit_btn">
         </div>
      </form>
   </div>
<?php
return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'contact_form', 'st_contact_form' );
```

I added below script in script file and validation is working. Now I want to know how to submit the form in wordpress? Should I create a table? or I have to create process.php file and add some logic?

```
$("#contact_form").validate({
rules: {
    name: {
        required:true
    },
    email: {
        required:true,
        email: true,
        emailExt: true
    },
    mobileno: {
        required:true,
        minlength: 10,
        maxlength: 10,
        number: true
    },
    type_of_services: {
        required:true
    },
    message: {
        required:true
    }
},
submitHandler: function(r) {
     if(isReqInprogress){
        return;
       }
    isReqInprogress = true;
    $.ajax({
                url:base_url+"/wp-content/themes/mytheme/process.php",

        type: "post",
        data:{name:name,email:email,mobileno:mobileno,type_of_services:type_of_services,message:message},
        dataType:"JSON",
        success: function(response) {
           alert("success");


    isReqInprogress = false;
        }


    })
}
});
```

**Process.php**

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$data = $_POST;
$to = $data['email'];
$subject = 'The subject';
$body = 'The email body content';
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

//$mail = wp_mail($data['email'], $subject, $body, $headers );
//if ($mail) {
    $wpdb->insert('wp_contact',
        array(
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'mobileno' => $data['mobileno'],
            'message' => $data['message'],
        ),
        array(
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
        )
    );
//}

?>
```

Would you help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got my solution,

I added below code in `function.php` and using shortcode I am getting my form on webpage

```
function st_contact_form(){
ob_start();
    ?>
      <div class="contact_form-wrapper popup-contact-form">
         <form action="" method="post" name="contact_form" id="contact_form" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="row">      
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
             <div class="form-group">
               <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" required>
             </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
             <div class="form-group">
               <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Id" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
    </div>
 </div>  
 <div class="row">    
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
         <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="mobileno" placeholder="Phone no" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
        <div class="form-group select-service">
            <select class="form-control" name="type_of_services" required>
                <option selected disabled>Select Service</option>
                <option value="1">Testing one</option>
                <option value="2">Testing two</option>

            </select>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 paddingLR0">
         <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Message" name="message" rows="2" required></textarea>
         </div>
    </div>
         <div class="form-group ">
            <input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit" class="btn_st btn_maroon form_submit_btn">
         </div>
      </form>
   </div>
<?php
return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'contact_form', 'st_contact_form' );
```

Now next step is, JQuery validation and Ajax. Also I created a `process.php` file in my theme

```
$("#contact_form").validate({
rules: {
    name: {
        required:true
    },
    email: {
        required:true,
        email: true
    },
    mobileno: {
        required:true,
        minlength: 10,
        maxlength: 10,
        number: true
    },
    type_of_services: {
        required:true
    },
    message: {
        required:true
    }
},
    
submitHandler: function(form) {
    if(isReqInprogress){
        return;
       }
        $.ajax({
        url:"/wp-content/themes/themename/process.php",
        type: "post",
        data:$('#contact_form').serialize(),           
        dataType:"JSON",
        success: function(response) {
            
        alert("Your message has been received and we will be contacting you shortly to follow-up.");
            isReqInprogress = false;
             }
    });
}
});
```

**Process.php**

Note: I have created a contact table in my database

```
<?php
define( 'BLOCK_LOAD', true );
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-config.php' );
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php' );
$wpdb = new wpdb( DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);

global $wpdb;        // <--- making $wpdb as global
$data = $_POST;
$query=$wpdb->insert('contact',
        array(
             'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'phone' => $data['mobileno'],
            'type_of_services' => $data['type_of_services'],
            'message' => $data['message']
        ),
        array(
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
        )
);


 if ($query) {
    $response['error'] = "true";

    }else{
    $response['error'] = "false";
    } 
echo json_encode($response);
exit();
    // $wpdb->show_errors(); 

?>
```

that's it. It's working perfectly for me.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you have to write code for inserting data in your process.php

```
global $wpdb;
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email= $_POST['email'];
$mob=$_POST['moblieno'];
$service_type=$_POST['type_of_service'];
$msg=$_POST['message'];
$wpdb->insert('tbl_name',array('name_field'=>$name,'email_field'=>$email,'service-field'=>$service_type,'message_field'=>$msg));
```

Comment: Yes, I updated the code but it's not woking. Can you help me?

Comment: can you share exact error or problem??

Comment: I am new in wordpress, I just created a form in function.php now I have to submit the form using ajax but i don't know how to do that in wordprees. I tried code which is in the question but that is not working.

Comment: try and print error $wpdb->show_errors(); with this and make sure your table name and field name are coorect

Comment: I added $wpdb->show_errors(); in my process.php file but the issue is when I fill the form and click on submit my page got refreshed. I think it is not calling process.php file. is my URL is correct?

Comment: Working with ajax in wordpress is bit different than in core php you have to define ajax url in your functions.php or in your custom plugin in your case .ajax url will not be the same as we do in core php  you need to call your ajax call with add_action('wp_ajax_my_ajax_action', 'my_ajax_action');and define ajaxurl with wp_localize_script( 'my_script_handle', 'ajaxurl', admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ); please check official doc https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins if you still have any issue please share it thank you